# How to set data to a variable from temporary table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have declared a temporary table

```
DECLARE @Table Table
(
  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  TableColumn VARCHAR(MAX)
) 

DECLARE @Temp VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Temp='SELECT * FROM '+'@Table'+''

SELECT @Temp
EXEC (@Temp)
```

I want to set all data of `@Table` to a variable `@Temp`. The above I tried practice is correct? Presently it shows some error.

> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the table variable "@Table".

[image]

I tried in the above methode then it shows error like

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>
> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 9
>
> Must declare the table variable "@Table". Msg 139, Level 15, State 1,
>   Line 0
>
> Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 17
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@Temp".

Comment: why use a string. just execute: Select * From @Table

Comment: @Jeremy I want to set the value to this string

Comment: your question is not clear. what are you trying to set?

Comment: and why are you trying to use dynamic SQL? just execute a select statement just like any other table. The table variable does not exist in the scope of the string when it is executed like that.

Comment: I think the execution flows for the `DECLARE` and `EXEC` are separate, thus you can't select data form @Table like that. Remove the dynamic SQL and just run the `SELECT * FROM @Table`, it will get you where you want.

Comment: Jeremy, I want to set all values from @Table  to variable

Comment: @Radu Gheorghiu, I want to set data dynamically

Comment: Your @table variable holds records like a regular table. you would need to concatenate what data you want from the table into a variable.

Comment: you are going down a very bad path. please explain at a higher level what you need. maybe we can help you think differently.

Comment: @SemilSebastian Set data dynamically? I'm not sure I understand what you mean..

Comment: @ Jeremy, I just want to set all data from my temporary table to a variable dynamically..Is it possible?

Comment: @SemilSebastian anything is possible. not everything is advisable. how do you want the data in your string represented? a table variable will hold multiple pieces of information, so you need to decide how you want any or all of the data to be represented in your string. with your given example, that is not clear.

Comment: Your question is not clear. First of all I would rather use temp table. But if you want table variable check: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05d8a/3/0. The clue is that with table variable you need to pass them to dynamic-sql. With temporary table you don't

Comment: @ Jeremy, I have a table named Student. If placed this table name in place of @Table it shows all datas from the student table.Likewise I want to display all data from my temporary table

Comment: @SemilSebastian I'd highly recommend against this approach. write code for the tables you have, and do NOT try to do things generically. You will encounter much pain with this approach. Just write the code you need, and move on.

Answer (score 0):

`EXEC()` creates new context, variables are not visible there so you need to pass them as argument. But temp table and normal tables are visible. This is why you get

> Must declare the table variable "@Table".

If you can change temp variables to temp tables.

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/5475/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE #Table
( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  TableColumn VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO #Table
VALUES ('aaa'), ('bbb');

DECLARE @Temp NVARCHAR(MAX) ='SELECT * FROM <placeholder>';

SET @Temp = REPLACE(@Temp, '<placeholder>', '#Table');

-- SELECT @Temp;

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
      @Temp;
```

If you want to query temp variables you need to create table type and pass to dynamic sql as argument like:

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05d8a/3/0)**

```
CREATE TYPE MyTable AS TABLE 
( 
 ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  TableColumn VARCHAR(MAX)
);

DECLARE @Table AS MyTable;

INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES ('aaa'), ('bbb');

DECLARE @Temp NVARCHAR(MAX) ='SELECT * FROM '+'@Table'+'';

-- SELECT @Temp;

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
      @Temp
      ,N'@Table MyTable READONLY'
      ,@Table;
```

Comment: @SemilSebastian Do you see difference temp variable vs temp table? You need to pass temp variable as argument to dynamic sql, see second demo

Comment: @SemilSebastian One thing, EXEC() creates new context, variables are not visible there so you need to pass them as argument. But temp table and normal tables are visible. This is why you get `Must declare the table variable "@Table".`

Comment: @  lad2025 2 ,   {Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 9
Must declare the table variable "@Table".
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 17
Must declare the scalar variable "@Temp".
} this much errors I got when I run it

Comment: @SemilSebastian I don't see your code, see fiddle demo, everything works as it should

Comment: @SemilSebastian or break to two lines `DECLARE @Temp VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Temp='SELECT * FROM '+'@Table'+''`

Comment: @ lad2025 , The same I just pasted but same error. What is this semi colon and all??

Comment: @SemilSebastian You should end each statement with `;`. In future version of SQL Server it will be mandatory

Comment: @    > 
> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
Must declare the table variable "@Table".
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 11
Must declare the scalar variable "@Temp"...same errors again

Comment: @SemilSebastian Do you use `EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]`? or still `EXEC()`

Comment: @SemilSebastian I don't have sql server 2008 installed, but it should work.

Comment: @SemilSebastian Try `DECLARE @Table MyTable;` without `AS`

Answer (score 0):

This is to show the difference between a table variable and a temp table. You can't do what you are trying to do. Also, @temp is just a variable to contain the SQL you want to execute. If you want the results in another variable, another will have to be declared.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,TableColumn VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

INSERT INTO @Table (TableColumn)
VALUES ('testing 1,2,3')

SELECT *
FROM @table --with table variables, you can only select in the scope

DECLARE @Temp VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Temp = 'SELECT * FROM @Table'

BEGIN TRY
    --SELECT @Temp
    EXEC (@Temp) --fails, because @table is not in scope
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 'Table variable dynamic execution failed'
END CATCH
GO

CREATE TABLE #table (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,TableColumn VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

INSERT INTO #Table (TableColumn)
VALUES ('testing 1,2,3')

DECLARE @Temp VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Temp = 'SELECT * FROM #Table' --you can select out of a temp table with dynamic sql, because it will remain in scope for called procedures

--SELECT @Temp
EXEC (@Temp) 
DROP TABLE #table
```

Comment: It works but #table will support by Azurewebsites(Cloud)

Comment: @SemilSebastian you need to provide aLL relevant information in your question in order for us to be effective. asking 100 questions about your intents and environments is not going to help us help you. as I stated before, state at a very high level what business problem you are trying to solve. More than likely, there is a different way to tackle what you want.

Comment: @ Jeremy, Sir, See my updated question.without using #table is it possible? Why beacause when I run your query in my cloud server it shows error(Azure cloud)